# Error con relaciones de tablas y con mostrar un valor en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo 4 tablas que se relacionan entre sí en mi base de datos en PhpMyAdmin; estoy haciendo un sitio en php con Laravel con Blade. Y resulta que quiero mostrar unos campos que en sí no tienen relación con una tabla principal que tengo, pero si con otras que se relacionan a su vez con la tabla principal.

Un ejemplo concreto sería lo siguiente.

Tengo una vista principal que me trae unos datos desde mi tabla **`reservas`** la cual hago un `join` con otras tablas dejo el codigo desde mi controlador en donde realizo todo.

```
public function index(){

    $usuario=Auth::user()->id;
    $reservas=Reserva::join('horario','horario.id','=','reserva.horario_id')
        ->join('cancha','cancha.id','=','horario.cancha_id')
        ->join('complejo','complejo.id','=','cancha.complejo_id')
        ->join('estado_reserva','estado_reserva.id','=','reserva.estado_reserva_id')
        ->where('horario.hora_inicio','>=',date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('complejo.id',Auth::user()->complejo_id)
        ->orderBy('horario.hora_inicio','asc')
        ->get(['reserva.id','complejo.nombre as complejo','cancha.nombre as cancha','cancha.deporte','horario.hora_inicio','estado_reserva.estado as estado']);

    return view('operador-reservas',['reservas'=> $reservas]);
}
```

Luego en mi vista tengo un boton que llama a la función **`editar`** de mi controlador. El cual el código es el siguiente.

**`EL BOTÓN`**

```
<a href="{{url('operador_reservas/'.$reserva->id.'/edit') }}">
    <input type="button" id="editar" value="MODIFICAR">
</a>
```

Mi controlador:

```
public function edit($id){

    $reserva = ReservasNew::find($id);
    $horario = HorariosNew::all();
    $complejo = ComplejosNew::find($id);
    $canchas = CanchasComplejo::find($id);

    return view('operador-reservas-modificar')->with('reserva', $reserva)->with('horario',$horario)->with('complejo', $complejo)->with('canchas', $canchas);
}
```

Y este es el campo el cual; en la nueva vista que retorna la función **`edit`**, quiero mostrar el nombre del complejo deportivo.

```
@if($complejo->cancha_id == $canchas->id)
    <input type="text" value="{{$complejo->nombre}}">   
@endif
```

Explico la relación de las tablas.

La tabla `complejos_deportivos` se relaciona con la tabla `canchas`, luego esta tabla **`canchas`** se relaciona con la tabla `horarios` y por ultimo la tabla **`horarios`** se relaciona con la tabla reservas.

De esta manera.

- reservas **->** horarios
- horarios **->** canchas
- canchas **->** complejos_deportivos

Y el error que obtengo es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que es lo que podría haber hecho mal en mi lógica?

Comment: Intenta imprimiendo el valor de $canchas para ver que tiene, pareciera que tu consulta $canchas = CanchasComplejo::all(); no devolvio resultados

Comment: Te refieres a un `dump();` si es eso ya he probado y me retorna `null`

Comment: si o puede ser un dd($canchas), si te retorna null entonces el error lo explica que estas haciendo referencia a una propiedad de un objeto que no existe, entonces para evitar el error condiciona, para este caso voy a dejar la condicion en una respuesta

Comment: @FranciscoQuijada. Edite la pregunta ya que de ese modo me trae `null` al momento de hacer un `dd()` o un `dump()`. Y respecto a tu respuesta quite los `@foreach` para no tener un problema de sintaxis y luego el campo que quiero mostrar la información aparece en blanco.

Comment: Entonces de la nueva forma que la pusiste buscando el id tampoco te trae resultados? ninguna de las dos variables $complejo ni $cancha?. El hecho que $complejo = ComplejosNew::all(); y $canchas = CanchasComplejo::all(); no te traiga resultados pareciera apuntar o que tus tablas estan vacias o que tu modelo no esta correcto,verifica eso, realizas el dd en el controlador o en la vista?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86467/discussion-between-francisco-quijada-and-m4urixd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO, posteo la solución a mi pregunta en caso de que a alguien más le sirva.

En el controlador:

```
public function edit($id){

    $reserva = ReservasNew::find($id);
    $horario = HorariosNew::all();

    //Se hace el llamado a la otra tabla mediante join()

    $complejo = DB::table('cancha')
        ->join('complejo', 'complejo.id','=', 'cancha.complejo_id')->get();

    $cancha = DB::table('complejo')
        ->join('cancha', 'cancha.complejo_id', '=', 'cancha.id')->get();

    return view('operador-reservas-modificar')->with(['reserva'=>$reserva,'horario'=>$horario,'complejo'=>$complejo, 'cancha'=>$cancha]);
}
```

Ahora en la vista

```
<!--DEJAMOS ESTOS INPUTs ESCONDIDOS
    #
    PORQUE ASÍ SE PUEDE MOSTRAR BIEN EL NOMBRE DEL COMPLEJO DEPORTIVO Y DE LA CANCHA-->

    @foreach($complejo as $complejo)
        @if($complejo->id == $complejo->complejo_id)
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$complejo->nombre}}">   
        @endif
    @endforeach

    @foreach($cancha as $cancha)
        @if($cancha->complejo_id == $cancha->id)
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$complejo->nombre}}">   
        @endif
    @endforeach
<!---->

<!--Y a continuación viene el verdadero campo, el input en su propiedad value="" se 
    debe llamar a la variable definida anteriormente en el controlador-->

<label class="text-label">Complejo</label>
<br>
<input type="text" value="{{$complejo->nombre}}" readonly="readonly" id="complejo">

<!--Se repiten estas 2 ultimas lineas para tambien agregar la otra variable definida 
    ($cancha) asignando su valor correspondiente en la propiedad value del input-->
```

Además, dejo la documentación en donde se explica todo de mejor manera: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar una condicion en tu foreach para el caso en el que alguna variable este vacia, puede ser de esta forma:

```
@if(isset($complejo) && isset($canchas))
  @foreach($complejo as $complejo)
    @foreach($canchas as $canchas)
        @if($complejo->cancha_id == $canchas->id)
            <input type="text" value="{{$complejo->nombre}}">   
        @endif
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Como está tu respuesta, solo me deja el campo en blanco. Y no me muestra el campo `nombre` de mi tabla  `complejos_deportivos.`

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de llamar a la vista desde el controlador, modifica tu sintaxis, así:

```
return view('operador-reservas-modificar')
    ->with([
        'reserva'=>$reserva,
        'horario'=>$horario,
        'complejo'=>$complejo,
        'canchas'=>$canchas
    ]);
```

No me preguntes, por qué, pero a un compa del curro le funcionó bien cuando la otra no le funcionaba. Yo siempre uso esta y me pasa bien todos los datos. Como la excepción te la lanza en la vista, me da que algún dato no te está pasando.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: voy a probar, gracias.